# array manipulation - How to remove a specific entry from array based on a condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, multidimensional-array

Im trying to filter an array but im not arriving at the expected solution.
Can someone please help. In this array i need to filter out if from.organization_details.type is 'SELLER_USER' and to.type value is 'OPERATOR'.
Also if from.organization_details.type == 'OPERATOR_USER' and to[0].type value is 'SHOP'

```html
[
    {
        "body": "Could you please elaborate on the discount",
        "from": {
            "display_name": "vandhana jayaprakash",
            "organization_details": {
                "display_name": "vandhana jayaprakash",
                "id": "2211",
                "type": "CUSTOMER"
            },
            "type": "CUSTOMER_USER"
        },
        "to": [
            {
                "display_name": "Taufiq Live Store",
                "id": "2001",
                "type": "SHOP"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "body": "for testing purpose",
        "from": {
            "display_name": "vandhana jayaprakash",
            "organization_details": {
                "display_name": "vandhana jayaprakash",
                "id": "2211",
                "type": "CUSTOMER"
            },
            "type": "CUSTOMER_USER"
        },
        "to": [
            {
                "display_name": "Taufiq Live Store",
                "id": "2001",
                "type": "SHOP"
            },
            {
                "display_name": "Operator",
                "type": "OPERATOR"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "body": "i need to know about warranty ",
        "from": {
            "display_name": "vandhana jayaprakash",
            "organization_details": {
                "display_name": "vandhana jayaprakash",
                "id": "2211",
                "type": "CUSTOMER"
            },
            "type": "CUSTOMER_USER"
        },
        "to": [
            {
                "display_name": "Taufiq Live Store",
                "id": "2001",
                "type": "SHOP"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "body": "this is a test messgae from seller on dec 17 21",
        "from": {
            "display_name": "taufiqpainter@gmail.com",
            "organization_details": {
                "display_name": "Taufiq Live Store",
                "id": "2001",
                "type": "SHOP"
            },
            "type": "SHOP_USER"
        },
        "to": [
            {
                "display_name": "vandhana jayaprakash",
                "id": "2211",
                "type": "CUSTOMER"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "body": "hi there",
        "from": {
            "display_name": "Operator",
            "organization_details": {
                "display_name": "Operator",
                "type": "OPERATOR"
            },
            "type": "OPERATOR_USER"
        },
        "to": [
            {
                "display_name": "Taufiq Live Store",
                "id": "2001",
                "type": "SHOP"
            },
            {
                "display_name": "vandhana jayaprakash",
                "id": "2211",
                "type": "CUSTOMER"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "body": "hello this is a test messsage on jan 5 2022",
        "from": {
            "display_name": "vandhana jayaprakash",
            "organization_details": {
                "display_name": "vandhana jayaprakash",
                "id": "2211",
                "type": "CUSTOMER"
            },
            "type": "CUSTOMER_USER"
        },
        "to": [
            {
                "display_name": "Taufiq Live Store",
                "id": "2001",
                "type": "SHOP"
            },
            {
                "display_name": "Operator",
                "type": "OPERATOR"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "body": "this is a message sent to operator ",
        "from": {
            "display_name": "taufiqpainter@gmail.com",
            "organization_details": {
                "display_name": "Taufiq Live Store",
                "id": "2001",
                "type": "SHOP"
            },
            "type": "SHOP_USER"
        },
        "to": [
            {
                "display_name": "Operator",
                "type": "OPERATOR"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "body": "this is a msg from operator to seller ",
        "from": {
            "display_name": "Operator",
            "organization_details": {
                "display_name": "Operator",
                "type": "OPERATOR"
            },
            "type": "OPERATOR_USER"
        },
        "to": [
            {
                "display_name": "Taufiq Live Store",
                "id": "2001",
                "type": "SHOP"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried below code (Please see fiddle link)  but its not working as expected. It eliminates the array entry if it contains to.type == 'CUSTOMER'. I want to eliminate only last two entries in my array.
Thanks in advance

https://jsfiddle.net/4m9kgfpv/

Comment: ``to`` is an array, there's no ``to.type``. Can you also describe more what should be filtered out

Comment: Hi @MajedBadawi i need to remove only those entries which is between seller and operator. i need to preserve all the entries which has customer in it.

Comment: for ``to``, you only want to check for the first element or if any of the elements matches? So you want to keep records where``from.organization_details.type`` is ``CUSTOMER`` or where ``to`` contains an element where ``type`` is ``CUSTOMER``?

Comment: i need to check if any of the element maches.. if in from object or to object if it has 'cusotmer'. then i need to preserve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), iterate over the array and keep the element if:

> `from.organization_details.type` is `CUSTOMER`

OR

> `to` has an element where `type` is `CUSTOMER` (use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some))

```js
const conferenceDays = [
  {
    "body": "Could you please elaborate on the discount",
    "from": {
      "display_name": "vandhana jayaprakash",
      "organization_details": { "display_name": "vandhana jayaprakash", "id": "2211", "type": "CUSTOMER" },
      "type": "CUSTOMER_USER"
    },
    "to": [
      { "display_name": "Taufiq Live Store", "id": "2001", "type": "SHOP" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "body": "for testing purpose",
    "from": {
      "display_name": "vandhana jayaprakash",
      "organization_details": { "display_name": "vandhana jayaprakash", "id": "2211", "type": "CUSTOMER"},
      "type": "CUSTOMER_USER"
    },
    "to": [
      { "display_name": "Taufiq Live Store", "id": "2001", "type": "SHOP" },
      { "display_name": "Operator", "type": "OPERATOR" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "body": "i need to know about warranty ",
    "from": {
      "display_name": "vandhana jayaprakash",
      "organization_details": { "display_name": "vandhana jayaprakash", "id": "2211", "type": "CUSTOMER" },
      "type": "CUSTOMER_USER"
    },
    "to": [
      { "display_name": "Taufiq Live Store", "id": "2001", "type": "SHOP" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "body": "this is a test messgae from seller on dec 17 21",
    "from": {
      "display_name": "taufiqpainter@gmail.com",
      "organization_details": { "display_name": "Taufiq Live Store", "id": "2001", "type": "SHOP" },
      "type": "SHOP_USER"
    },
    "to": [
      { "display_name": "vandhana jayaprakash", "id": "2211", "type": "CUSTOMER" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "body": "hi there",
    "from": {
      "display_name": "Operator",
      "organization_details": { "display_name": "Operator", "type": "OPERATOR" },
      "type": "OPERATOR_USER"
    },
    "to": [
      { "display_name": "Taufiq Live Store", "id": "2001", "type": "SHOP" },
      { "display_name": "vandhana jayaprakash", "id": "2211", "type": "CUSTOMER" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "body": "hello this is a test messsage on jan 5 2022",
    "from": {
      "display_name": "vandhana jayaprakash",
      "organization_details": { "display_name": "vandhana jayaprakash", "id": "2211", "type": "CUSTOMER" },
      "type": "CUSTOMER_USER"
    },
    "to": [
      { "display_name": "Taufiq Live Store", "id": "2001", "type": "SHOP" },
      { "display_name": "Operator", "type": "OPERATOR" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "body": "this is a message sent to operator ",
    "from": {
      "display_name": "taufiqpainter@gmail.com",
      "organization_details": { "display_name": "Taufiq Live Store", "id": "2001", "type": "SHOP" },
      "type": "SHOP_USER"
    },
    "to": [
      { "display_name": "Operator", "type": "OPERATOR" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "body": "this is a msg from operator to seller ",
    "from": {
      "display_name": "Operator",
      "organization_details": { "display_name": "Operator", "type": "OPERATOR" },
      "type": "OPERATOR_USER"
    },
    "to": [
      { "display_name": "Taufiq Live Store", "id": "2001", "type": "SHOP" }
    ]
  }
];

const arr = conferenceDays.filter(({ from = {}, to = [] }) =>
  (from.organization_details.type === 'CUSTOMER') || 
  (to.some(({ type }) => type === 'CUSTOMER'))
);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted to achieve. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

there is function called filter for arrays that does exactly what you want, you can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), but i write an example here aswell.

imagine we have and array and and we wanna filter all the values that are lower or equal to 2, we should create such a condition in array.filter callback that only values more than 2 return true. in your case you just need to check properties to match what you want, hope that helped.

```js
    let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    console.log(array.filter(element => {
        return element > 2;
    }));
```

Comment: thanks for the information. could you please help me with the array provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution. it will work if you have only 1 element in your ***to*** array

```js
const arr = [
    {
        body: "Could you please elaborate on the discount",
        from: {
            display_name: "vandhana jayaprakash",
            organization_details: {
                display_name: "vandhana jayaprakash",
                id: "2211",
                type: "SELLER_USER",
            },
            type: "CUSTOMER_USER",
        },
        to: [
            {
                display_name: "Taufiq Live Store",
                id: "2001",
                type: "OPERATOR",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        body: "for testing purpose",
        from: {
            display_name: "vandhana jayaprakash",
            organization_details: {
                display_name: "vandhana jayaprakash",
                id: "2211",
                type: "CUSTOMER",
            },
            type: "CUSTOMER_USER",
        },
        to: [
            {
                display_name: "Taufiq Live Store",
                id: "2001",
                type: "SHOP",
            },
            {
                display_name: "Operator",
                type: "OPERATOR",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        body: "i need to know about warranty ",
        from: {
            display_name: "vandhana jayaprakash",
            organization_details: {
                display_name: "vandhana jayaprakash",
                id: "2211",
                type: "CUSTOMER",
            },
            type: "CUSTOMER_USER",
        },
        to: [
            {
                display_name: "Taufiq Live Store",
                id: "2001",
                type: "SHOP",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        body: "this is a test messgae from seller on dec 17 21",
        from: {
            display_name: "taufiqpainter@gmail.com",
            organization_details: {
                display_name: "Taufiq Live Store",
                id: "2001",
                type: "SHOP",
            },
            type: "SHOP_USER",
        },
        to: [
            {
                display_name: "vandhana jayaprakash",
                id: "2211",
                type: "CUSTOMER",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        body: "hi there",
        from: {
            display_name: "Operator",
            organization_details: {
                display_name: "Operator",
                type: "OPERATOR",
            },
            type: "OPERATOR_USER",
        },
        to: [
            {
                display_name: "Taufiq Live Store",
                id: "2001",
                type: "SHOP",
            },
            {
                display_name: "vandhana jayaprakash",
                id: "2211",
                type: "CUSTOMER",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        body: "hello this is a test messsage on jan 5 2022",
        from: {
            display_name: "vandhana jayaprakash",
            organization_details: {
                display_name: "vandhana jayaprakash",
                id: "2211",
                type: "CUSTOMER",
            },
            type: "CUSTOMER_USER",
        },
        to: [
            {
                display_name: "Taufiq Live Store",
                id: "2001",
                type: "SHOP",
            },
            {
                display_name: "Operator",
                type: "OPERATOR",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        body: "this is a message sent to operator ",
        from: {
            display_name: "taufiqpainter@gmail.com",
            organization_details: {
                display_name: "Taufiq Live Store",
                id: "2001",
                type: "SHOP",
            },
            type: "SHOP_USER",
        },
        to: [
            {
                display_name: "Operator",
                type: "OPERATOR",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        body: "this is a msg from operator to seller ",
        from: {
            display_name: "Operator",
            organization_details: {
                display_name: "Operator",
                type: "OPERATOR",
            },
            type: "OPERATOR_USER",
        },
        to: [
            {
                display_name: "Taufiq Live Store",
                id: "2001",
                type: "SHOP",
            },
        ],
    },
];

// Previous array length
console.log(arr.length);

arr.forEach((value, i) => {
// If the condition is true than remove that value from the array
if (
    (value.from.organization_details.type == "SELLER_USER" &&
        value.to[0].type === "OPERATOR") ||
    (value.from.organization_details.type == "OPERATOR_USER" && value.to[0].type === "SHOP")
) {
    arr.splice(i, 1);
}
});

// Array length after removing data from array
console.log(arr.length);
```

Comment: BTW, to produce the situation I have changed the first element from.organization_details.type value as there were no SELLER_USER value

Comment: Hello @ar.arif i need to remove only those entries which is between seller and operator. i need to preserve all the entries which has customer in it.

Comment: Ok, then the code would be slightly different let me change this code.
because this code is filtering not removing

Comment: @vandu Now this code will remove the entries if they match the condition. check the length of the array before and after. Hope it will help you

Comment: this code is giving those entries between seller and operator. But i want only those which involves customer, i need to eliminate entry between seller and operator